# Printing the current minute in a loop with python

Tags: python

I'm using python 3 and trying to create a script that runs constantly, and at some time, execute a specific code.
The code i have so far, verifies the current minute, and if it's above a given minute, it print's a message, otherwise, it prints the current minute and waits 5 seconds and try again.
The problem is that it only prints the minute the code started.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
hour = now.hour
minute = now.minute
L=1

while (L == 1):
    if minute > 39:
        print ("It's past "+str(hour)+":"+str(minute))
        L = 2
    else:
        print(str(minute))
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Because as soon as you print, you set `L` to 2, so the while loop is false. Also, you're not redefining `now` inside the while loop, so it will always have the time of the program starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some programming pointers:

1) To make a constant loop use the following construct:

```
while (True):
   if (...):
       ....
       break
```

2) The time stored in your "now" variable is static must be updated with the new time within the loop:

```
while (True):
    now = datetime.now()
```

So:

```
while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    if now.minute > 39:
        print "Hour, Minute:", now.hour, now.minute
        print "All done!"
        break 
    else:
        print ""Minute, second:", now.minute, now.second
    time.sleep(5)
```

3) In "real life" (TM) calculate the time you want to wait until your event and sleep that long.

```
now = time.now()
if now.minute >= 39:
    minutesToEvent  = 0
else:
    minutesToEvent = 39 - now.minute
print "Sleep seconds to next event:", minutesToEvent * 60
sleep(minutesToEvent * 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to insert the assigments

```
now = datetime.now()
hour = now.hour
minute = now.minute
```

inside the while loop, or they'll not be refreshed

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the value of the `now` variable in every step of the loop. Also, I removed unncessary variable `L` and replaced it with `while True` to make the code nicer.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    if now.minute > 39:
        print ("It's past "+str(hour)+":"+str(minute))
        # Run your desired code here.
    else:
        print(str(minute))
        time.sleep(5)
```